# The Perfect Date

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, story, music

I decided to take my new girlfriend Fey out on a nice all-day date. This is how it happened.

> She doesn't like surprises, so I started by telling her what the day would entail.
>
> We went downtown to see the parade; we saw a number of bands comes strolling by.
>
> The music got her so excited that my sweet date stood up and improvised a little jig in front of everyone.
>
> As we walked to our destination we took a detour through the Slavic market where Fey bought a souvenir.
>
> We got to our location but saw there was a cute Arabian espresso place next door. We stopped in real quick.
>
> The main event was a traditional Chinese tea ceremony. That was my favorite part of the day.
>
> We finished the date by walking along the river as the tall plants swayed and whistled in the wind.
>
> She was so impressed by the date that she bent down and picked three flowers and gave them to me one at a time.

All in all I say it was a perfect day. Now tell me, what did we do on our date?

Hint #1:

> Added a helpful tag

Hint #2:

> My girlfriend's name is important for understanding line 3.

Because @rm-vanda got the answer correct, I will most likely be selecting his answer as the correct one. However, I will also award 50 rep to whomever can explain all eight lines as well as why they are in this particular order.

Comment: I am guessing the helpful tag is Rot13(zhfvp)? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer - 
I have to throw this out there, because it parallels too well, but I'm not 100% sure...

> you took her to see the Nutcracker -

More broadly

> each clue relates clues to a dance in Act II, No. 12 & 13 of the Nutcracker

---

She doesn't like surprises, so I started by telling her what the day would entail.

> Think this is just self-referential.

We went downtown to see the parade; we saw a number of bands comes strolling by.

> In Act II, No. 12 of the Nutcracker-many dancers from various cultures dance to music from their culture.

The music got her so excited that my sweet date stood up and improvised a little jig in front of everyone.

> Likely referring to the Spanish dance, which is first.

As we walked to our destination we took a detour through the Slavic market where Fey bought a souvenir.

> not sure about this one since it's out of order from the next three, which are otherwise in the same order as the ballet.

We got to our location but saw there was a cute Arabian espresso place next door. We stopped in real quick.

> In the ballet, Arabic dance is the "Coffee" dance..

The main event was a traditional Chinese tea ceremony. That was my favorite part of the day.

> Likewise, the Chinese dance is the "Tea" dance, and follows the Arabic dance

We finished the date by walking along the river as the tall plants swayed and whistled in the wind.

> And "Dance of the Reed-Pipes" follows the order.

She was so impressed by the date that she bent down and picked three flowers and gave them to me one at a time.

> Matches up with Waltz of the flowers, which is No 13.

Comment: Your answer is correct! But some of your explanations for the first four lines are wrong. I'll accept the answer if you can accurately say what movement each line refers to (even the first line)

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to have to find a video where I can watch the performance and reflect on what I'm missing...

Comment: Should be able to get them just from the titles. Go beyond just numbers 12 &13. The ordering may seem strange but there's a reason for it.

Answer (score 4):

Like rm-vanda already found out, you went to

> a performance of The Nutcracker by Tchaikovsky, but I think it was not the ballet, but the suite, [Op. 71a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nutcracker#Tchaikovsky:_The_Nutcracker_Suite,_Op._71a). Each line refers to one movement.

She doesn't like surprises, so I started by telling her what the day would entail.

> Ouverture miniature: An overture is an introduction to the suite

We went downtown to see the parade; we saw a number of bands comes strolling by.

> Marche: a parade usually has a lot of marching, also bands on a parade might be marching bands

The music got her so excited that my sweet date stood up and improvised a little jig in front of everyone.

> Danse de la Fée Dragée: Dance of the Sugar Plum Fairy. Here *my sweet* refers to the sugar, also the name of your date is Fey, which is similar to the French Fée

As we walked to our destination we took a detour through the Slavic market where Fey bought a souvenir.

> Danse russe Trepak: Russians are Slavic people.

We got to our location but saw there was a cute Arabian espresso place next door. We stopped in real quick.

> Danse arabe: Arabian dance, hence the Arabian espresso place. This piece is also called *Le café* in the ballet.

The main event was a traditional Chinese tea ceremony. That was my favorite part of the day.

> Danse chinoise: Chinese dance also called *Le thé* in the ballet.

We finished the date by walking along the river as the tall plants swayed and whistled in the wind.

> Danse des mirlitons: Dance of the Reed Flutes. Reed usually grows near  the water like at a river and is rather tall. Reed flutes are wind instruments and a kind of whistles.

She was so impressed by the date that she bent down and picked three flowers and gave them to me one at a time.

> Valse des fleurs: Waltz of the Flowers, it's a waltz and therefore in three-four time.

Comment: Exactly correct! Good job!